# Excel VBA method workbooks.open fails after downloading and opening multiple excel files

Tags: excel, vba

Hello people of the internets!
As the title suggests, I've been having some issues with my vba code lately. More specifically, I have coded the following function, which gets an array of dates as input and then downloads and opens the corresponding excel workbooks from a web site, one at a time, copies a specific range, pastes it to `thisWorkbook` and then closes the downloaded workbook.

```
Public Function henexDownload(ByRef auctionDates() As Date, ByVal firstEmptyRow As Long)
Const lagieURL = "http://www.lagie.gr/fileadmin/user_upload/reports/DayAheadSchedulingResults/"
Const henexURL = "http://www.enexgroup.gr/fileadmin/user_upload/reports/DayAheadSchedulingResults/"
Dim tempRNG As Range
Dim tempWorkbook As Workbook
Dim requestURL As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim d As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Set tempRNG = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prices").Cells.Find(What:="HENEX", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
j = tempRNG.Column
For d = LBound(auctionDates) To UBound(auctionDates)
    i = firstEmptyRow
    fileName = Format(auctionDates(d), "yyyymmdd") + "_DayAheadSchedulingResults_01.xls"
    If Year(auctionDates(d)) >= 2018 Then
        requestURL = henexURL + fileName
    Else
        requestURL = lagieURL + fileName
    End If
    If URLExists(requestURL) Then
        Set tempWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(requestURL)
        tempWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C7:Y7").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prices").Cells(i, j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        tempWorkbook.Close (False)
    Else
        MsgBox "The requested file:" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + fileName + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "is not available.", vbCritical
    End If
    firstEmptyRow = firstEmptyRow + 24
    'ThisWorkbook.Save
Next d
End Function
```

The code works exactly as expected up to a random number of iterations. 
The first time I observed this issue, this number was 15. 
The code would consistently crash at the 16th iteration with a message saying "Sorry we couldn't open ....", where ... is the url of the file.
After doing some research on the internet, I came across some issues that seem to be similar. In these cases some people suggested that the workbook should be saved once in a while so that excel's cache is flushed. I tried this without any luck.
Rebooting my pc seems to have generally increased the number of iterations before the code crashes, but it still does randomly crash.
It should be noted that the crash is not dependent on whether the file exists or not. It only seems to be related to the number of files that are being processed.
Could this be a memory related issue? Could it be related to temporary files?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The `URLExists` function as follows:

```
Public Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean 'checks if the URL actually exists
    Dim request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo endNow
    Set request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
endNow:
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute with F8 Step by step to see if it fails?

Comment: Do you mean that it produces your message, "The requested file..."? And where does the function `URLExists` come from?

Comment: Hi Andy. No it does not produce my message. The files and the corresponding links exist. It's some default excel message saying "Sorry we couldn't open *file link*." I edited the original post to include the URLexists function, although i don't think the issue is related to it.